# Bootstrap modal not displaying properly

Tags: html, wordpress, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm facing an issue, where the bootstrap modal is not displayed correctly. The modal can be toggled. If it's toggled, it appears as another DOM element in the flow, instead of a dialog. Here's what I mean:

[image]

**What I've tried:**

I've manually enqueued the jquery and bootstrap javascripts and check their paths. They're valid. For debugging purposes I've taken the sample code from the bootstrap documentation and put it up on a separate page([Go there](https://www.feldmusikschwyz.ch/modal-demo/)). Same result. I've tested other websites using modals, so it's definitely not some weird browser issue.

My guess is it either being a dependency problem or a conflict with the wordpress theme I'm using. I've run out on ideas how to fix this, any help is deeply appreciated.

**Dependencies:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you didn't import the CSS file. I checked your site. You only included bootstrap layout CSS and didn't include the modal.css. please include the modal.css.And popper.js file has an issue. please upgrade the js file.

Comment: I see, thank you. I included the bootstrap modal and modalmanager.js as well as the two .css files related to modals, that are hosted on [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-modal). Now the modal shows, but with some weird content alignment. I don't have much time right now, but I guess I'll be able to fix the rest. Regarding the popper.js: There's no newer version availale. I will have to fix that error some other way. And again: Thank you very much!